# Flash - How do I dynamically pass XML node name to an external function?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, nodes

I want to know how to pass an XML node name to an AS3 function on a different file. For example I have a Flash Movie that contains a button, which upon being clicked passes the required name of the XML node to an external AS3 file which then uses it to access all the contents within the XML node name's element.

Comment: Would you be so kind and provide some more information. Runs the external SWF in a separate Flash Player instance or do load it into the main Flash movie?

Answer (score 0):

*"... passes the required name of the XML node to an external AS3 file"* can mean a number of things, which you'll have to clarify to get the correct answer.

Is the AS3 file...

- another class which you're instantiating in your document code?
- another swf that was loaded inside your currently running SWF?
- another external swf running inside another instance of Flash Player?
- an included .as file?

I'll try to answer this the best way I can.

Let's assume that your function that ran in location A, has access to XML file Z.
Function B (whose location will remain nameless) also has access to XML file Z.
Your query is how to pass a reference to X location in Z from A to B.

I'm also going to assume that the way in which you choose to pass info from A to B is not pertinent (since that's wholly dependent on the above listed scenarios which could affect this).

See [How to Traverse XML structures](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e6b.html).

At this point, you could pass a string representation of the path (such as `"order.book[0].title[0]"`) to B.  From B, you could pull the node using the string with [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath).  AS3 being ECMAScript doesn't have this natively, but you can easily import it via [xpath-as3](http://code.google.com/p/xpath-as3/).

Sorry to be so vague, but without more info, it's the best I can offer.

---

**Dd Daym:** You removed your question just as I was about to answer it ([AS3 Reset Position of Droptarget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901788/as3-reset-position-of-droptarget)). Sadly StackOverlow offers no PM, so rather than dump my 30 minutes of effort, [here's your solution](http://www.atriace.com/media/DropCD.as).